# Downloading image stored as a BLOB does not work

Tags: php, database, mysqli, blob

My script returns a file which has a proper name but it is without any filetype or extension. When I open this file it shows just very long almost infinite string of characters. I want to return an image (.png file) and I specified MIME type for it in

header("Content-type: image/png");
My script is:

```
    $query = "SELECT * " ."FROM images WHERE filename = '$name2'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) 
       or die('Error, query failed');
list($file, $content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-type: image/png");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
mysqli_close($connect);
exit;
```

And the echoed file is just infinite string of characters like that:

¸A<'^ą~`U–°ŹĘŘC.

It doesn't convert the BLOB into proper filetype (.png)

Comment: please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009763/download-blob-image-stored-in-the-database-to-my-computer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download blob image (stored in the database) to my computer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43009763/download-blob-image-stored-in-the-database-to-my-computer)

Comment: Can you explain me a little more? I am just a newbie:(

Comment: Sure, just go to the link and read the accepted answer, it is well explained,

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$connection =  mysqli_connect("localhost","root"," ",your_database)
           or die('Database Connection Failed');
mysqli_set_charset($connection,'utf-8');

$id = 1;

 // Use a prepared statement in production to avoid SQL injection;
 // we can get away with this here because we're the only ones who
 // are going to use this script.
$query = "SELECT * " ."FROM images WHERE filename = '$name2'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect,$query) 
   or die('Error, query failed');
list($id, $file, $type, $size,$content) = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
ob_clean();
flush();
echo $content;
mysqli_close($connection);
exit;

?>
```

It is worked for me!!

Comment: I do not store the size. Should I?

Comment: The same question when it comes to filetype. I don't store it in the database because I set it up hardcoding it in the code: header("Content-type: image/png"); instead of: header("Content-type: $type"); Should I store it also?